# When I add a row in Excel to copy the previous row's formatting, can I also copy the form control checkboxes?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table with checkboxes in certain columns (see sample table)-- they are linked to their cells and also move/size with the cells. I also added text box "headings" throughout the table so visually when you filter for checked boxes, you see under which heading the checked item is in (I know I could create a separate column for that, but it works if I add text to the cells underneath the heading that I keep checked when filtering).

[image]

I want to be able to add rows at the end of each section, or before the next heading, since the formatting changes slightly in each section. However, I also want to add the checkboxes, and my code currently doesn't do that. It's okay if they're not linked to the new cell-- I have another macro I can run to do that.

Here's what my code would look like in the sample table:

```
Sub Add_Row_Pepperoni()

Rows(7).Insert , xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End Sub

Sub Add_Row_Pineapple()

Rows(13).Insert , xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End Sub
```

And I would like to add "Next" to "Call" this code:

```
Sub Link_CheckBoxes()
Dim chk As CheckBox
Dim lCol As Long
lCol = 0 'number of columns to the right for link
For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
   With chk
      .LinkedCell = _
         .TopLeftCell.Offset(0, lCol).Address
   End With
Next chk
End Sub
```

My other concern is the row I'm referencing (here rows 7 and 13) will change every time I add a row above it (I'll no longer be referencing the "header" row). Any tips?